# SPF records clarification of using A mechanism

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, spf

What is the difference between using `v=spf1 a ~all` and `v=spf1 ip4:IP_OF_A_RECORD ~all` or `v=spf1 IP_OF_A_RECORD ~all` when configuring SPF records? Which way is correct and more robust and reliable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either `v=spf1 a ~all` and `v=spf1 ip4:IP_OF_A_RECORD ~all` would be suitable entries for a mail server.  However the `~all` negates most of the value of having an SPF record.  Use of `-all` would be much better, and would be suitable for the entry for a mail server.  With rare exceptions, no other server should be sending email on behalf of a mail server.

The `a` mechanism might invoke an extra DNS lookup, but is is likely the lookup has already been done.

According to my reading of the documentation `v=spf1 IP_OF_A_RECORD ~all` is wrong.

For a sending domain I would recommend `v=spf1 mx -all`.  Note, that this requires all Internet bound email for the domain to be sent via its mail exchange servers.  This should not be an onerous requirement.

For any (sub)domains which should not send email I would recommend  `v=spf1 -all`.  This will advertise that this domain should not be used in email addresses.

You may want to review my recommendations on [Securing your Email Reputation with SPF](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/securing-your-email-reputation-with-spf/) and or the [OpenSPF](http://www.openspf.org) site.

Comment: I will go with 'v=spf1 a:domain.name -all' then. Thank you for you quick and descriptive answer.

Comment: Bill, your two recommenations (for a sending domain, and for a non-sending subdomain) are identical.  Is this deliberate?

Comment: @BillThor, the SPF for email-disabled subdomains should have no "mx" mechanism. Although having no MX records published for the subdomain is in effect the same as `v=spf1 -all`, there is an extra DNS lookup to be performed.

Comment: @MadHatter I've corrected the non-sending domain.  Missed cleanup up the paste. Thanks

Comment: @ValeraTumash Mail should be sent from an `mx` using a sub-domain such as `smtp.example.com`.   Raw domains such as `example.com` tend to be used by spambots rather than legitimate mailers.

Comment: @BillThor, sure. I meant that I will use 'a' part of a record as shown, there is much more with 'mx' and 'include' ones. Thanks.